# Кто такая матрешка?

Tags: этимология

Название куклы матрешки произошло от русского имени Матрена, как я понимаю. А почему именно это имя взято? Случайно, или есть какая-то история?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Имя в прошлом весьма распространенное, но скорее всего ничего конкретного за ним не стоит. 
Аналогично трудно найти реальный прообраз у Ваньки-встаньки, Петрушки или самоварной "Маши".

Comment: А может, Матрёна (несмотря на "родство" с Матроной) - имя простонародное? Ну, а матрешка - она тоже не аристократка.

Comment: Не улавливаю мысль. Матрёну можно считать простонародным вариантом имени Матрона (хотя это чисто фонетический вариант, никак не сословный), но дальше-то что? Это как-то объясняет наделением им семейства деревянных куколок?

ЗЫ Я спрашиваю, не возражаю. Пока.

Comment: Ну, не то, чтобы объясняет, но все же. Не назовут же ее, скажем, Жанной или Элеонорой!  

А насчет сословного варианта - не знаю. Для меня при имени "Матрёна" всплывает в уме отнюдь не аристократка. Хотя, конечно, не знаю, как было с этим во времена возникновения этих кукол.  

Смутно вспоминается еще история с Пушкиным, который дал дочери гетмана имя Мария, хотя на самом деле она была Матрена. Может, тоже показалось простовато?

Comment: Имена Пушкинских героев - дело довольно интимное.
В качестве одно из предположений могу сказать, что Пушкинский образ очень далек от реальной дочери гетмана, женщины очень ограниченной и . 

Тем не менее, хотелось бы видеть от Вас более внятно сформулированную мысль. Какое имя или вариант имени вы считаете простонародным - и какое благородным. Иначе Ваше суждение не многого стоит.

Comment: Какая разница, что считаю я. Важно, как считали люди 19 века (тогда, кажется, придумали эту игрушку?) Но этих сведений у меня нет, об этом я и спросила.

Comment: Вопроса в Ваших словах не вижу. 
Поскольку третий раз переспрашивать считаю уже неприличным, просто скажу, что не могу поддержать сию беседу.

Comment: Господи, случайное замечание превратили в дискуссию. Ну несогласны -  и не надо, я высказала только робкое предположение.

Answer (score 1):

Вот что говорит об истории [Википедия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D1%91%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B0):

Русскую деревянную куклу назвали матрёшкой. Сделано это было неслучайно. В дореволюционной провинции имена Матрёна, Матрёша считались одними из наиболее распространённых женских имён, в основе которых лежит слово «матерь». Эти имена ассоциировалось с матерью многочисленного семейства, обладавшей хорошим здоровьем и дородной фигурой. Впоследствии оно сделалось нарицательным и стало означать токарное разъёмное красочно расписанное деревянное изделие. Но и по сей день матрёшка остаётся символом материнства, плодородия, поскольку кукла с многочисленным кукольным семейством прекрасно выражает образную основу этого древнейшего символа человеческой культуры.

Answer (score 0):

**DocentI**, 
А каким было Ваше предположение? 
И С чем был несогласен невинно убиенный Бегемотус?
Я не вижу по тексту никакой дискуссии. Вас хотели переспросить - а Вы обиделись.

Comment: Я? Нисколько не обиделась, я на Вас давно не обижаюсь. И вообще не склонна к этому. Для меня этот форум -просто развлечение, я только огорчалась немного из-за грубости кое-кого . Да и то это вроде потешных боев, уж извините. А про матушку я просто подумала, что именно это имя носили в то время многие деревенские бабы, красноречие да ядерные. Вот и ждала ответа от кого-то, кто знает состояние изменника 19 века.

Comment: Это не обида, просто усталость. У Вас, наверное, тоже так бывает: скажешь что-то походя, а собеседник начинает прикапываться , что да почему. Уж и не рада, что сказала.

Comment: >из-за грубости кое-кого  
  
Ну положим, не только огорчались, но и активно провоцировали.  
Ладно, мне Ваши отношения фиолетовы (цэ).

Про матрёшку, пожалуйста. Я всё ещё не улавливаю мысли. 
Предположение (?) о простонародном характере имени, касалось в первую очередь того что оно было распространено среди низших сословий (полагаю - да), или того, что его не встречалось "в верхах" (тут - не знаю)? И второй вопрос. Вы подразумеваете, что матрешка - это обязательно что-то лубочное, крестьянское? Это не так. Матрёшек для и царицы из фарфора делали. Вот не знаю, правда, как называлм.

Comment: Андрей, давайте Вы сами сформулируйте и мой вопрос, и свой ответ. Я не интересуюсь матрешками , их названием и вообще пойду порешаю что-нибудь на математике

Comment: А кто тут Андрей?
Вы думаете, он Вас понял настолько, чтобы решать за вас?

Comment: Вам то что? Пусть Андрей и отвечает )))) и вообще, пора закрывать дискуссию. Мне эта тема смерти надоела...

Answer (score -1):

Матрёшка это Матрёна. А имя Матрёна означает *почтенная дама, госпожа, мать семьи, матушка*.

Наша матрёшка — мамочка с семейством.

Comment: Вы смешиваете "матрона" и "Матрёна".  А у них не более чем случайное фонетическое сходство.